# Count elements in a nested list in an elegant way

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have nested tuples in a list like

```
l = [(1, 'a', 'b'), (2, 'b', 'c'), (3, 'e', 'a')]
```

I want to know how many 'a' and 'b' in the list in total. So I currently use the following code to get the result.

```
amount_a_and_b = len([None for _, elem2, elem3 in l if elem2 == 'a' or elem3 == 'b'])
```

But I got `amount_a_and_b = 1`, so how to get the right answer?

Also, is there a more elegant way (less code or higher performance or using builtins) to do this?

Comment: Is this actually a bottleneck in your program?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sorry, I have updated my answer.

Comment: I rolled back your last edit, because that changes the nature of your question *entirely*, which is not fair to everyone that answered the previous version of your question. `sum(1 for t in l if '-' not in t)` would achieve your other version.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's ok. It seam is the best choice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd flatten the list with [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) and pass it to a [`collections.Counter()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

counts = Counter(chain.from_iterable(l))
amount_a_and_b = counts['a'] + counts['b']
```

Or use `sum()` to count how many times a value appears in the flattened sequence:

```
from itertools import chain

amount_a_and_b = sum(1 for v in chain.from_iterable(l) if v in {'a', 'b'})
```

The two approaches are pretty much comparable in speed on Python 3.5.1 on my Macbook Pro (OS X 10.11):

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> l = [(1, 'a', 'b'), (2, 'b', 'c'), (3, 'e', 'a')] * 1000  # make it interesting
>>> def counter():
...     counts = Counter(chain.from_iterable(l))
...     counts['a'] + counts['b']
...
>>> def summing():
...     sum(1 for v in chain.from_iterable(l) if v in {'a', 'b'})
...
>>> timeit(counter, number=1000)
0.5640139860006457
>>> timeit(summing, number=1000)
0.6066895100011607
```

Comment: Creating the set outside is faster

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: in Python 2 or 3? I can only get it (slightly) slower with a closure for the set. Take into account that the `in {...}` is peephole optimised, the set is stored as a `frozenset()` in the code object constants and a `LOAD_CONST` opcode is used to load it each iteration.

Comment: ~20 percent faster using 3.5.2

Comment: `st = {"a","b"}` then `sum(1 for v in chain.from_iterable(l) if v in st)` vs `sum(1 for v in chain.from_iterable(l) if v in {'a', 'b'})
` *2.12ms vs 2.54ms*

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: in a *function*? `st` is then a closure, and can't be turned into a constant. `LOAD_DEREF` has to do more work than `LOAD_CONST`, so I'm finding this a little hard to believe. Plus, I tried exactly that and can't reproduce the speed boost you seem to have found.

Comment: Not in a function, just running from ipython, since you don't believe words, here is a picture http://pasteboard.co/uzaZZcoi.png, using *Python 3.5.2 (default, Jul  5 2016, 12:43:10)*

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: I didn't say I didn't believe you; I am expression doubt and can't reproduce the numbers. I'll have a look at ipython and what magic it applies to squeeze 20% out of a constant.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: figured it out. `ipython` will *re-compile the whole expression* each run. That means that it'll create a new `frozenset()` constant each time, which isn't exactly comperable to compiling the expression just once then executing it 1000 times.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: put the whole thing in a *function* first, then use `%timeit` on that.

Answer (score 1):

You want to avoid putting data in a datastructure. The `[...]` syntax constructs a new list and fills it with the content you put in `...` , after which the length of the array is taken and the array is never used. If the list if very large, this uses a lot of memory, and it is inelegant in general. You can also use iterators to loop over the existing data structure, e.g., like so:

```py
sum(sum(c in ('a', 'b') for c in t) for t in l)
```

The `c in ('a', 'b')` predicate is a bool which evaluates to a 0 or 1 when cast to an int, causing the `sum()` to only count the tuple entry if the predicate evaluates to `True`.

Comment: This is over 3 times as slow: `1.9530742168426514` against the same timed tests

Comment: nitpick: *cast* is not the right term; `bool` is just a subclass of `int` and as such `True` and `False` are *integers already*. No casting is needed, they just have an integer value when added up.

Comment: It is indeed slower than `summing` because the chain iterator is probably implemented natively, making it more efficient than a nested loop in pure Python. However, on my machine it is faster than the `counter` method. I do like the readability and it uses no helper functions, so for small arrays I would use this. I agree that the chain iterator is better for cases where the array is potentially large.

Comment: Are you testing on Python 2 perhaps? `Counter` got a C-optimisation in Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, functional method using reduce:

```
>>> l = [(1, 'a', 'b'), (2, 'b', 'c'), (3, 'e', 'a')]
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: (1 if 'a' in y else 0) + (1 if 'b' in y else 0) + x, l, 0)
4
```

Comment: I can't reproduce these timings at all. `reduced()` is about 25% slower at 0.7757142429982196.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, just runned it again, still almost the same results...maybe processor stuff? Ill try on my laptop

Comment: What version of Python? I'm using 3.5.1 on an OS X Macbook Pro.

Comment: And the numbers *make no sense*. The `lambda` executes a hell of a lot of bytecode for each tuple in `l`. No way that'll be faster than a single set membership test each iteration for the `sum()` approach.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, just tried on 3.5.1 on W10, true, from 0.77 to 0.85 or so.

Comment: In Python 2.7 the `Counter` object is not optimised (it is just a pure Python subclass of `dict`), and `variable in {...}` is not peephole optimised; there I can get timings comparable to this.

Comment: the answer was on a xeon with python 2.7.12 :/

Comment: Note the Python 3 tag on the question!

Comment: Yep, sorry, will change it

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over both the list and the sub-lists in one list comprehension:

```
len([i for sub_list in l for i in sub_list if i in ("a", "b")])
```

I think that's fairly concise.

To avoid creating a temporary list, you could use a generator expression to create a sequence of 1s and pass that to `sum`:

```
sum(1 for sub_list in l for i in sub_list if i in ("a", "b"))
```

Comment: The `in (..)` tuple test is slower in this cases, but mostly because the small strings `'a'` and `'b'` can be interned (so an identity test is used when testing for set membership, which is just a pointer comparison).

Comment: However, I used `sum()` from the start because, as you note creating a list object just to get the length is a waste of memory (and memory allocation takes time too!)

Answer (score 0):

Although this question already has an accepted answer, just wondering why all of them as so complex. I would think that this would suffice.

```
>>> l = [(1, 'a', 'b'), (2, 'b', 'c'), (3, 'e', 'a')]
>>> total = sum(tup.count('a') + tup.count('b') for tup in l)
>>> total
4
```

Or

```
>>> total = sum(1 for tup in l for v in tup if v in {'a', 'b'})
```

Comment: Using `tuple.count()` does a full traverse of each tuple, in C code. You do this twice now; `itertools.chain.from_iterable()` only needs to iterate each tuple once. As a result, this approach takes `0.9097697560064262`, a good 60% more time.

Comment: The second option is of comparable speed; the bytecode has to iterate over the same number of steps as `chain.from_iterable()`, so you end up with `0.5921581570000853.